# grab cursor in windows chrome

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am getting two cursors in windows chrome version 31.0.1650.57
The two cursor are grab and a default arrow. I have used below CSS

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:maroon;
    border:1px solid #000;
    cursor:grab;
    cursor:-moz-grab;
    cursor:-webkit-grab;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jL9ft/

Please let me know what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: I only get the grab cursor in the same version of Chrome, unless I'm outside of the square.

Comment: I am getting only grab cursor in all browsers except windows7 chrome where I am getting 2 cursors. I am using windows7 on virtual box.

Comment: Could be a virtual box problem then. I'm running Windows 7 x64 and it's working fine for me on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Used cursor as image from here - http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur

```
div {
   cursor:url(../images/openhand.cur) 4 4, move
}
```