# Crossbrowser GRAB cursor (-moz, -webkit)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, mouse-cursor

I'm trying to customize the behavior of the cursor. Now it works next way: on mousemove I use:

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "move");
```

onmmouse up:

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "auto");
```

In this case:

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "-moz-grab");
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "-webkit-grab");
```

the cursor only works for **-webkit(Chrome)**.

While this case

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "-webkit-grab");
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "-moz-grab");
```

the cursor only works for **-moz(FF)**.

The following structure hasn't worked as I expected:

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "-moz-grab, -webkit-grab");
```

This works:

```
scheme.setAttribute("style", "cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:-webkit-grab;");
```

In both browsers, but I [read here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) that it's bad practice.

---

The code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pjphmm/) works but I need to use a structure like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pjphmm/1) and [that](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pjphmm/2).

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pjphmm/3/) (that structure doesn't work now).

---

### Edit 1

From this [other Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325782/grab-cursor-in-windows-chrome):

solution using:

```
scheme.setAttribute("cursor", "url(http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/openhand.cur) 4 4, move");
```

works in both browsers, but still needed a solution using `-moz-grab` and `-webkit-grab` values.

[link here](http://jsfiddle.net/r7pjphmm/4/)

And it does not seem to work in IE (I expect to see second, reserve move icon)

---

### Edit 2

Clearer, mousedown/mouseup example:

[**Case 1:**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfvjvukv/) (works only Chrome)

[**Case 2:**](http://jsfiddle.net/dfvjvukv/1/) (here there are no changes on mousedown)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In accordance with J.Steve's answer:

```
.grabbable {
    cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

 /* (Optional) Apply a "closed-hand" cursor during drag operation. */
.grabbable:active { 
    cursor: grabbing;
    cursor: -moz-grabbing;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

from here [CSS for grabbing cursors (drag & drop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors?rq=1)
and this comments

***are you sure a comma-list still works? I'm using cursor:move;
 cursor:-webkit-grab; cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:grab; with most
 preferred last***

***the comma-list works if you're specifying multiple formats like
 cursor: url(example.svg#linkcursor), url(hyper.cur), pointer***

In my case I set CCS options

`item.setAttribute("style", "cursor: move; cursor: grab; cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:-webkit-grab;");`

and unset them by

`item.setAttribute("style", "cursor: auto;");` after my cancel event(mouseup).

---

> http://jsfiddle.net/gwau7r9r/

JS:

```
var item = document.getElementById("changeCurArea");
    item.addEventListener("mousedown", func, false);
    item.addEventListener("mouseup", func1, false);

    function func() {
        item.setAttribute("style", "cursor: move; cursor: grab; cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:-webkit-grab;");
    }

    function func1() {
        // item.setAttribute("cursor", "auto");
        item.setAttribute("style", "cursor: auto;");
    }
```

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="350" viewBox="200 150">
    <rect id="mySvgArea" width="400" height="350" stroke="black" fill="lightgrey"></rect>
    <rect id="changeCurArea" x="100" y="100" width="200" height="150" stroke="red" fill="pink"></rect>
</svg>
```